# Python, tcpServer tcpClient, [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

When I try to run tcpServer and tcpClient on the same local network, it works, but I can't run them on the external network. The OS refuses the connection.

> Main builtins.ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I checked whether tcpServer is running or not using netstat, and it is in the listening state.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are most likely two reasons for that:

1.) Your server application is not listening on that particular ip/port

2.) A firewall is blocking that ip/port

I would recommend checking your firewall settings. You could start with turning your firewall off to determine if it really is a firewall issue.

If so, just add an accept rule for your webservice (ip:port).

edit: And check your routing configuration if you are in a more or less complex network. Make sure that both networks can reach each other (e.g. ping the hosts or try to connect via telnet).